# Handling quotes inside quotes in a bibliographic field

Tags: bibtex, punctuation, quoting, nesting

I have an entry in my bib file of the form

```
@conference{abc,
author = "Some name",
title = ""This is inside quote" and outside quote content",
.
.
.
}
```

when I check this entry through [jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/), I get an error saying that `= is expected but found '"'`. This is because the inside quote is not escaped. I looked into it and I found that we can allow `"` by putting it inside `{}`, like `{"}`. But if I do that I don't get `"This is inside quote" and outside quote content` as title instead I get `{"}This is inside quote{"} and outside quote content`. Can anyone please suggest me how to handle this?

Comment: Try:
title = {"This is inside quote" and outside quote content}

Comment: To distinguish between quotes as *delimiters* of a field within a bib entry and quotes with *typographic* meaning, you could write `title = "\`\`This is inside quote'' and outside quote content"`. Of course, if your typographic preference is to use single quotes rather than double quotes, you'd type `title = "\`This is inside quote' and outside quote content"`. Or, as @PLK suggests, you could elect not to use `"` as a field delimiter and employ `{` and `}` instead.

Comment: yes, I think in my case what @PLK suggested is the good solution. thanks!

Comment: I always use {} as delimiters for all fields in .bib files - it saves confusion.

Comment: regardless of using quotes for the delimiters of a bibtex element, using the non-directional `"` with tex will almost always result in doubled closing quotes in the output.  much better to do as @Mico suggests and use intentional directional quotes, single or double as appropriate.

Comment: You could try marking up the quotes using a command.  E.g. either `\qq` from `textcmds` or `\enquote` from [csquotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mico and Barbara Beeton have already commented that using -- as appropriate -- double quotes (``` `` ```/ `''`) or single quotes (`` ` ``/`'`) for quotes with typographic meaning will resolve your error. And Andrew Swann has suggested to use commands like `\enquote` from the [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package for marking quotes within `.bib` files. I'll add that for users of [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) there's another reason to do so: Depending on your bibliography style, article titles (contrary to book titles) may be put inside (outer) quotes, which means you should use *inner* quotes within article titles, but *outer* quotes within book titles, but only *for those bibliography styles*. Simply using `\enquote` spares you the hassle of keeping track of style requirements and quote nesting levels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {An article title with a \enquote{quote}},
  journaltitle = {A journal},
  number = {1},
  pages = {1--4},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {A book title with a \enquote{quote}},
  location = {Somewhere},
  publisher = {A publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The other reason is that some bibliographical styles require "American punctuation," like Chicago, while others rely on the 'British style', which `biblatex` and `csquotes` will handle correctly if one loads `babel` with the respective languages.

Comment: Nice! But if one prefers to keep the bib database in title case and relies on a bibtex/biblatex style to downgrade it to sentence case then `\enquote{Quote}` won't lowercase. It's better to add another level of bracing: `{\enquote{Quote}}`.