# In biblatex, how to exchange the places of left and right quotation marks?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

In biblatex,  how do I exchange the places of left and right quotation marks?

Please see this example. I am trying to achieve something like this.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: You should be using the `csquotes` package and the options it provides to adjust these.

Answer (score 2):

Like Andrew said in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144617/in-biblatex-how-to-exchange-the-places-of-left-and-right-quotation-marks#comment327329_144617), you should use `csquotes` package which will automatically format quotations according to the language declared.

You could do this by adding these lines :

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

Ans then, using `\enquote{quote}` inside your .bib file.

For more informations, you could be interested by this question : [Handling quotes inside quotes in a bibliographic field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65331/handling-quotes-inside-quotes-in-a-bibliographic-field)

Comment: Please note though that if one wants to enclose the title of an article or something similar (i.e. an entire field) one should not enclose it in any quotation marks in the `.bib` file, but let `biblatex` or your BibTeX bibliograohy style wrap the `title` field in quotation marks (this can be done in `biblatex` via `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}`).