# How to add a double quotation mark to a word in the title of an article in .bib file?

Tags: bibtex

The output should be:

Author name (2017) A very "interesting" paper. *Journal name*, 2(1): 20-30.

How to get the quotes as in the word *interesting*.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{filecontents*}{finalref.bib}
@article{start,
author = {Author name},
title = {A very interesting article},
journal = {Journal name},
volume        = {2},
number        = {1},
pages          = {20-30},
year          = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\bibliography{finalref}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't compile your code...

Comment: I removed the comma after the year. Can you compile it now?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I am sorry, I was using my own edited .bst file. I have changed it to the standard apalike. Can you compile the MWE now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package `csquotes` and the command `\enquote{...}` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66339/123129)).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents*}{finalref.bib}
@article{start,
author = {Author name},
title = {A very \enquote{interesting} article},
journal = {Journal name},
volume        = {2},
number        = {1},
pages          = {20-30},
year          = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\bibliography{finalref}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In LaTeX `"` should not be used for quotation mark, which makes the conflict in *.bib. Simply write ``` title = {A very ``interesting'' article}' (please observe two apostophes after ```interesting`).

Comment: This is possibly not helping. It gives error, Undefined control sequence... with \â€œ interesting\â

Comment: An error should be earlier: you have `page` instead of `pages`.

Comment: Corrected it! But still I do not get the desired output.

Comment: Oh, you have also a spurious backslash before finalref.bib!

Comment: Yep! removed it..

Answer (score 0):

For special capitalization and punctuation in the bibliography, I have always had success just enclosing the special part in braces.

```
title = {A very {``interesting''} article},
```

It works if you need special capitalization too, e.g., ``` title = {A very {``InTeresTinG''} article}, ```

And, as others have noted, use two ticks instead of " to make the marks face correctly.